# Uses for brewers/nutritional yeast?

Tags: culinary-uses, seasoning

I grew up putting this stuff on my popcorn and absolutely love it.  I recently found out that you can also put it on salads that have a vinaigrette dressing and it's also delicious.  Are there other common applications that I am not aware of?

FYI - Brewers/nutritional yeast != baking yeast

Comment: Brewer's yeast is not the same as nutritional yeast; each is grown in a different medium. Most people people prefer nutritional yeast, which also has a better nutritional profile.

Comment: Was going to suggest putting it on popcorn. Damn, you beat me to it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a great addition in just about any clear stock soup (non-cream-based) such as chicken, beef and even vegetable. (It's actually great for vegetarians and vegans who may have difficulty getting enough of their b-complex due to a meatless diet.) It enriches and deepens the flavor while providing a bunch of minerals. It's also an easy way to "rescue" a soup whose depth of flavor and savoriness (umami) fell short.

Couple of caveats:

- It might make your stock cloudy if
  you add too much
- It doesn't seem to
  stay in solution in stock too well. Needs frequent stirring in the bowl
  to keep a consistent flavor

Answer (score 1):

You can also use it as a base for vegan mac and "cheese".

We used to make this in college all the time.  I forget the exact portions, but about 2 cups soy milk, 1 cup nutritional yeast, a little soy sauce, hot sauce and cornstarch to thicken it if needed.

It's not so bad.

Also I like it sprinkled on cooked kale and other greens -- especially when mixed with tahini and yogurt.